# How to install wunderlist on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: wunderlist

I cannot install wunderlist from the Software Center. Can anyone help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: Probably relevant from the related questions section: [How do I install wunderlist?](/q/62300/175814)

Answer (score 2):

A version compatible with 14.04 isn't available on the Software Centre. However, you can install it as a Chrome extension or Firefox add-on. There are links available from their official download page here: https://www.wunderlist.com/download/